# List.innerHTML, why is it needed (javascript)

Tags: javascript

In the function udskriv() it says List.innerHTML, i tried the code without it and it seems to work fine. So why is it there? This a an assignement i got from my teacher, we were supposed to write the code of a paper and try to figure out what it does.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>Tingle 2.0</title>
    <script>
        var db = [];
        var ting = {};

        function gemData(){
            x = Form1.Hvad.value;
            y = Form1.Hvor.value;
            ting = {Hvad:x,Hvor:y}
            db.push(ting);
            Form1.reset();
        };

        function udskriv(){
            for (i=0;i<db.length;i++){
                document.getElementById("List").innerHTML = List.innerHTML + db[i].Hvad + " " + db[i].Hvor + "<br>";
            }
        };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h2>Tingle</h2>
    <p>Registrer eitt nýtt ting</p>
    <form name="Form1"> 
        Hvad:
        <input type="text" name="Hvad">
        Hvor:
        <input type="text" name="Hvor"> <br><br>
        Vís alt
        <input type="button" onclick="gemData()" value="Gem Data">
        <input type="button" onclick="udskriv()" value="Udskriv">
    </form>
    <p id="List"></p>
</body>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

udskriv() is appending new items to the list. Function gemData() will add a new object containing x and y as keys to db. As you can see, db is a collection of ting objects. When you click on second button, List is updated with new entries, as you are iterating over all the objects in db and appending it to innerHTML of list.

innerHTML is a DOM attribute that specifies inner content of a node.

Comment: So what your saying is that List.innerHTML appends the item to db?

Comment: Ahhh now I get it. What it does it displays the previous text in the <p id="list"> So that when I add another input, it doesnt remove the previous one

Answer (score 0):

`List` is referring to `<p id="List"></p>`. In the `udskriv()` you are appending all text from the db to the list element.

The code will not work without the `udskriv()` function as there is nothing that appends the db text then.